# how c# application can retrieve data from php in an efficient manner

Tags: c#, php, data-retrieval, posting

Below is my php code which works fine:

```
<?php

//This script checks the id and code of the already registered user from the database. If correct it returns the other details otherwise the respective error

//starting session
session_start();

//catching data from client
$id=$_POST['id'];
$code=$_POST['code'];

if($id&&$code)//checking if the data is not empty
{
    //Connecting to server
    ($connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ohhell')) or exit("Connection Failed");

    //Selecting user for given id
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");

    //Counting number of rows
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        //Creating associative array
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        //freeing result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        //fetching code from database
        $db_code=$row['code'];
        $code=md5($code);

        //checking if the codes match
        if($code==$db_code)
        {
            //change status
            mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE users SET status='yellow' WHERE id='$id'");

            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
            $_SESSION['location']=$row['location'];

            $name=$row['name'];
            $location=$row['location'];

            //closing connection
            mysqli_close($connect);

            //returning values to client
            exit("$name\n$location");//Successful Login. Client can now create an object and switch the screen
        }
        else
        {
            exit("Invalid Player Code");//Unsuccessful Login
        }
    }
    else
        exit("Invalid Player ID");//Unsuccessful Login
}
else
    exit("Incomplete Details");//Unsuccessful Login
```

?>

It returns the respective error message or the corresponding details of the player to the c# client. Below is the client side code to receive the data:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
Stream dataStream;
WebResponse response;
StreamReader reader;

response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

After receiving the data successfully the c# client separates both the data with the help of "\n" and then makes an object of a class and fill the received data to the respective data members of that class.

Now here comes the problem, since I am testing now everything is working fine. But, my question is that, as the data being read is going to be in the form of string, how can I make sure at the client side that the data is actually received successfully and the string that is retrieved actually contains the data and not the error message.

I mean suppose if an internal error occurs while connecting to php or any other network error returns the corresponding error that too would be in the form of string, now how I am going to differentiate that whether the the client app should start separating the data from the string to make the object or it should terminate with an error.
For the errors that I have included in my php I can use respective if() conditions in the c# client but that's not a proper way as the errors are not guaranteed to be limited to the considered errors in the php script. There might be a numerous number of errors that can be returned so what approach should be taken in this case to actually differentiate between the error and real data.

On possible approach is to prepend a signal say "1" to the data before sending it and to test for the signal at the client's side whether the received string starts with a "1". If yes then going for the separation else displaying the corresponding error message. But this approach is also not optimal as in the case the if the error itself starts with 1, it will fail.

So what should be actually done to send data to c# in an optimal way through a php script?

Sorry for the long description! Waiting for assistance!!!

Thanks a million billion trillion...:)

Comment: Can't you directly access the database?

Comment: Try JSON or XML, more about those you find on google

Comment: @ReeCube can I achieve all my requirements for the program trying JSON or XML. If yes can you point me to specific tutorials. I have no idea about these two. Also which one to prefer among both?

Comment: Added a answer with the reference to this question.

Comment: @YairNevet I simply don't have to because of a million reasons!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [http status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to indicate error conditions.
It seems currently you're only using `200 OK` (by default), but e.g. `Invalid Player Code` could result in a `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden` (if that's meant for some kind of authorization).

On the c# side you'd get that status code via the [HttpWebResponse.StatusCode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTTP Status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to determine weather or not an error occured.
You php could set the respective HTTP header if an error occurs during the run of said php script i.e. using [http_response_code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).
If the Startus code is okay, you can parse the response (as said in the comments, using [json](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation)) and retrieve the results. In case an error occured in the network communication, you produce the respective error yourself in the client. If an error occured in PHP, you retrieve the error by also parsing the response, thereby retrieving the error message.

Simple Example in PHP

```
$response = array();
$responseCode = null;
try {
  // some code is executed
  $responseCode = 200;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // an error occured and we have to add it to our response
  $response['error'] = array('errorcode' => $e->getCode(), 'error' => $e->getMessage());
  $responseCode = 500;
}

http_response_code($responseCode);
echo(json_encode($response ));
```

Now in your c#, simply check the header. If it is 500 (*meaning an error occured*), json_decode the result and get the error. If it is 200 (*meaning OK*), json_encode the result. If it is anything else, responde to it according to the linkes HTTP Error Code list.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the comment-question of Vikas Prasad: *"@ReeCube can I achieve all my requirements for the program trying JSON or XML. If yes can you point me to specific tutorials. I have no idea about these two. Also which one to prefer among both?"*

**JSON or XML** are just the way how you **transfer the data** and how you read them after, you **need php and c# to use JSON or XML**. I **prefer JSON** but im not sure how well it's working on C#, I've never tested it.

[Here you can find an JSON API for C#.](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

But first you should add JSON for your PHP-server. On PHP, **JSON is very easy** to use, there is an [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. In your case, you just need the [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) function, because on the server side, you just want to generate the JSON for the client. How to use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) is very **well supported by Google and the PHP documentation**, but if you have questions, just ask in a comment.

Here is a little example:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: ok, one more doubt?
What about sending values not as string but as actual integer.
how to accomplish this thing using json?

Comment: In JSON you can use Arrays, Strings, Numbers, Booleans, Objects and NULLs. This means if you write 6 its a number (integer) if you write "6" its a text (string) if you write true or false its a boolean. Try a look on Wikipedia about JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it.
One more help please?
Can you please explain me the use of:
JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize

Comment: Why or how do you need this? normally json_encode and json_decode should do their work with your arrays and values...

Comment: No, I do not need it. Actually as you told me about JSON, I thought of studying about it before actually implementing it. So I understood everything except this Serialize stuff.
That's why I asked to you. Nothing serious...:p

Comment: Ah ok, this is good ;)  I'm not sure, I never used this but I think this is to make you able to use json_encode and json_decode with your own objects

Comment: Well, Again in a problem, I used the json to send an associative array from php to the c# cleint. The json string received at the client is this:
"{\"name\":\"VISHAL\",\"location\":\"GWL\"}"
Now, I want to know that why are these extra backslashes before each quote.
When I output the same script on my browser through a localhost, it shows correct ouptut like this:
{"name":"VISHAL PARADKAR","location":"PADAV, GWALIOR"}
There are no extra backslahes in the output.
Please help???
Need your help very badly!!!

Comment: those backslashes are normal, because your string starts with " and ends with ", if there wouldn't be backslashes, the c# interpreter won't be able to say where the string starts and where it ends and if you use \" in a ""-string, it'll be interpreted as " sign in the string, hope my declaration was clear

Comment: Well, first of all thank god you are back...:)

Second, I already know what you explained.

Third, I know why those backslashes are there and printing the string on the console removes those backslashes, but I am de-serializing the received object from php in the c# client to make a class for it directly and because of those backslashes its not working...:(

Need your help very badly???

Comment: are you sure the backslashes are the problem? try this string: @"{"name":"VISHAL","location":"GWL"}"

Comment: else try to open a new question about this, you can link it here then and i'll answer on the new question and other people too, because i have a date now, i cant answer you until tomorrow :)